# How to carry lag values and sum with another attribute using R?

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse, lubridate, mutate

## Required library

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

### Create data

```
df <- data.frame(AreaID = c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'),
Period = c('24/07/2023', '25/07/2023', '26/07/2023','27/07/2023', '28/07/2023', '29/07/2023', '30/07/2023', '31/07/2023', '1/08/2023', '2/08/2023', '3/08/2023', '4/08/2023', '5/08/2023', '6/08/2023', '24/07/2023', '25/07/2023', '26/07/2023','27/07/2023', '28/07/2023', '29/07/2023', '30/07/2023', '31/07/2023', '1/08/2023', '2/08/2023', '3/08/2023', '4/08/2023', '5/08/2023', '6/08/2023'),
Day = c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'),

ItemA = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 9, 8, 12, 10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 9, 8, 12, 10, 11, 12, 13),

ItemB = c(150, 110, 140, 130, 140, 100, 110, 190, 180, 120, 100, 110, 120, 170,150, 110, 140, 130, 140, 100, 110, 190, 180, 120, 100, 110, 120, 170 ),
Schedule = c('1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'))
```

In this above data (i.e., df), for variable "Schedule" 1 means ItemA quantity was delivered and 0 means ItemA quantity was not delivered. If Schedule is 0 for any day, then for part A, I need to deduct ItemA from ItemB; for part B, I need to carry ItemA value for the immediate following day Schedule where it is 1 and add with ItemB. Note there is no delivery on Sunday (i.e., for all Sunday, Schedule is 0).

I tried as below and solved part A but couldn't reach solution for part B.

## Part A

```
df %>%
  mutate(ItemB = case_when(Day == "Monday" & Schedule == 0 ~ ItemB - ItemA,
                           Day == "Tuesday" & Schedule == 0 ~ ItemB - ItemA,
                           Day == "Wednesday" & Schedule == 0 ~ ItemB - ItemA,
                           Day == "Thursday" & Schedule == 0 ~ ItemB - ItemA,
                           Day == "Friday" & Schedule == 0 ~ ItemB - ItemA,
                           Day == "Saturday" & Schedule == 0 ~ ItemB - ItemA,
                           Day == "Sunday" & Schedule == 0 ~ ItemB - ItemA,
                           TRUE ~ ItemB
                           ))
```

### Require output

```
Output <- data.frame(AreaID = c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'),
Period = c('24/07/2023', '25/07/2023', '26/07/2023','27/07/2023', '28/07/2023', '29/07/2023', '30/07/2023', '31/07/2023', '1/08/2023', '2/08/2023', '3/08/2023', '4/08/2023', '5/08/2023', '6/08/2023', '24/07/2023', '25/07/2023', '26/07/2023','27/07/2023', '28/07/2023', '29/07/2023', '30/07/2023', '31/07/2023', '1/08/2023', '2/08/2023', '3/08/2023', '4/08/2023', '5/08/2023', '6/08/2023'),
Day = c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'),

ItemA = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 9, 8, 12, 10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 9, 8, 12, 10, 11, 12, 13),

ItemB = c(150, 110, 140, 117, 153, 90, 99, 211, 180, 120, 90, 120, 108, 157,175, 110, 140, 117, 153, 90, 99, 211, 180, 120, 90, 120, 108, 157),
Schedule = c('1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'))
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how can I solve this part B? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the correct solution for my question. I have modified the codes proposed by Mark in this post based on the question requirement to achieve the correct solution. I highly appreciate Mark's contribution as well.

```
# Modified Mark's codes

processor <- function(deliv_df) {
    rollover_value <- 0

    for (i in seq_along(deliv_df$ItemA)) {
        if (deliv_df$Schedule[i] == 0) {
            deliv_df$ItemB[i] <- deliv_df$ItemB[i] - deliv_df$ItemA[i]
             rollover_value =  rollover_value + deliv_df$ItemA[i]
        }
        else if (deliv_df$Schedule[i] == 1 & rollover_value > 0) {
            deliv_df$ItemB[i] <- deliv_df$ItemB[i] + rollover_value
            rollover_value <- 0
        }
        else if (deliv_df$Schedule[i] == 1 & rollover_value == 0) {
            deliv_df$ItemB[i] <- deliv_df$ItemB[i]
            rollover_value <- 0
        }
    }

    return(deliv_df)
}

processor(df)
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks a lot for your contribution in this solution. The above is the correct solution for my question.